# Threaded DirectX access for two cameras with Delphi XE3, shows the last one duplicated

Tags: multithreading, delphi, camera, multimedia

I have an app working fine that accesses two different web cameras at once using DirectX selecting them with comboboxes. The probem is doing it in the main thread almost freezes both cameras and works veeeeeery bad. So, my idea was to run each camera stuff in a separate thread. The probem now is that the threaded version changes first image to the last setted camera.

Is it not possible to access cameras from separate threads?
Im using also VFrames library from
https://github.com/MakeMagazinDE/GRBLize/blob/master/VFrames.pas

```
type
    TCamAThrd = class(TThread)
    private
        fVideoImage : TVideoImage;
        fVideoBitmap: TBitmap;
    protected
        constructor Create;
    public
        procedure OnNewVideoFrame(Sender : TObject; Width, Height: integer; DataPtr: pointer);
        procedure Execute; override;
end;

type
    TCamBThrd = class(TThread)
    private
        fVideoImageB : TVideoImage;
        fVideoBitmapB: TBitmap;
    protected
        constructor Create;
    public
        procedure OnNewVideoFrameB(Sender : TObject; Width, Height: integer; DataPtr: pointer);
        procedure Execute; override;
end;

constructor TCamAThrd.Create;
begin
    fVideoBitmap    := TBitmap.create;
    fVideoImage     := TVideoImage.Create;
    fVideoImage.OnNewVideoFrame := OnNewVideoFrame;
    Inherited Create(True);
end;

constructor TCamBThrd.Create;
begin
    fVideoBitmapB := TBitmap.create;
    fVideoImageB  := TVideoImage.Create;
    fVideoImageB.OnNewVideoFrame := OnNewVideoFrameB;
    Inherited Create(True);
end;

procedure TCamAThrd.Execute;
begin
    CoInitialize(nil);
    CamASelected := MainForm.ComboBox1.items[MainForm.ComboBox1.itemindex];
    fVideoImage.VideoStart(CamASelected);
end;

procedure TCamBThrd.Execute;
begin
    CoInitialize(nil);
    CamBSelected := MainForm.ComboBox2.items[MainForm.ComboBox2.itemindex];
    fVideoImageB.VideoStart(CamBSelected);
end;

procedure TCamAThrd.OnNewVideoFrame(Sender : TObject; Width, Height: integer; DataPtr: pointer);
begin
    fVideoImage.GetBitmap(fVideoBitmap);
    Synchronize(nil, procedure begin MainForm.Image1.picture.bitmap.assign(fVideoBitmap); end);
end;

procedure TCamBThrd.OnNewVideoFrameB(Sender : TObject; Width, Height: integer; DataPtr: pointer);
begin
    fVideoImageB.GetBitmap(fVideoBitmapB);
    Synchronize(nil, procedure begin MainForm.Image2.picture.bitmap.assign(fVideoBitmapB); end);
end;
```

I am trying to show two cameras in separated panels at once on screen. When I use threads, I only get the last set cam duplicated.

Comment: Is this library VFrames from GRBLize? Is so then I have my doubts about that being thread-safe (`AllocateHWND`). Secondly you are accessing VCL visual components from your `Execute` methods in a non-thread-safe manner. Don't do that. It does not seem that this library will be helping you in anyway because it posts a message to the hidden window created by `AllocateHWND` which then calls the `OnNewVideoFrame` instead of just calling `OnNewVideoFrame` from inside the `CallBack` and expecting you to then handle the Synchronization from there

Comment: If this library is any good the way it was written then I would suggest you take it and modify it to be thread-safe. A thread can have its own message queue without the need for `AllocateHWND`. Have a look at `PeekMessage` and message queues

Comment: Yes, you can access cameras from separate threads as long at the code that does the accessing and "providing-to-frontend" keeps threads in mind

Comment: Why do you have two thread classes? The code inside is the same, so you clearly need same functionality. Just delete one of those and create two thread instances of the same class. Those objects are completely separate entities. Also your constructor is declared as protected which may lead to you calling wrong constructor in code. It should be public.  And on top of everything already said, there is not enough code to understand thread-safety as it also depends on the types you are using. You are lacking proper [mcve]

Comment: The identifier fMessageHWND (in VFrames) is setted when each TVideoImages is created.  Why this value i changed for the first Thread withour call constructor. Perhas this is code issue but my my knowledge is far from enough to fix is PostMessage(fMessageHWND, fMsgNewFrame, Size, integer(fImagePtr[i]));

Comment: I personally would not use that library unless I made heavy modifications to it for thread-safety as well as the ability to skip captured frames when needed. I do suggest you give it a try to modify it to at least get the thread-safety in order but maybe you should look elsewehere if you struggle to do that.